# How to install php5-ldap extension while the server is offline on linux ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

i am trying to install php5-ldap extension on my server which is ubuntu 16 and this server has no access to the internet, how do i go about?
Note: i have tried .deb files still i have not managed to solve the problem,
but when i used .deb files this error was coming out

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/ldap.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/ldap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/ldap.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/ldap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Please someone help me to figure this out.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple install on ubuntu desktop and copy this binary extensions to `/usr/lib/php/20131226/ldap.so` but this bad way. Better way download source and copy to server

```
$ cd /path/to/source
$ phpize
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make test
$ make install
```

but I can't find this extension, I think you need compile php with support ldap `--with-ldap`

Comment: I have tried the above method but i am getting this error during compilation, configure: error: xml2-config not found. Please check your libxml2 installation. Even after installing libxml2 still getting the same error. Also, i have searched for ldap.so file without success so far.